# WPF DataGridCheckBoxColumn not clickable when using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have the following datagrid

```
    <DataGrid
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Grid.Row="1"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            SelectionUnit="FullRow"
            SelectionMode="Single"
    Height="auto"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding TableSummaries }">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Source Table" Binding="{Binding SourceTableFullName}" Width="4*"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="EDW Schema"  Binding="{Binding SchemaName}" Width="2*"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="EDW Table" Binding="{Binding TableName}" Width="4*"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

and int the viewmodel i have the property

```
public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
```

when the application is running the check boxes show up but they are not clickable. i can't check them or do anything to them

Am i missing something?

thanks!

UPDATE:

I added IsReadOnly = "false" to the datagrid to just see if that was it and still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue TableSummaries was an IEumerable and it needed to implement IList and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What if you used a template column instead

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="CheckBox"  >
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox Binding="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Does that work?

Also, do you get any binding errors in your output window when you run the application and have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: using this gives me an ambiguous reference error on the Binding of the checkbox